# Setting binding of subproperty

Tags: silverlight, xaml, binding, mvvm

I have an element on the my usercontrol

```
<myControls:MonitorWindow x:Name="WindowFrame" MinHeight="400" />
```

and I need to change its subproperty

```
MonitorWindow.CloseButton.Visibility.
```

Is it possible bind property from ViewModel to that property?

One way is ElementBinding with TwoWay Mode to fake field, but it isn't very nice.

Comment: do you want the Visibility property to be the source of the binding?  Usually, it's the other way around.  You bind the visibility to a property on the ViewModel like:  <Button x:Name="CloseButton" Visibility="{Binding MyViewModel.IsCloseButtonVisible, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}" />

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should Make a `Dependency Property` of the Type Visibility so that its can be binded to your control and can be set from outside the control.

For Ex Let the Dependency Property is named as CloseButtonVisibility  is present in codebehaind of your user Control (use `propdp` then `press TAB or double TAB` as snippet shortcut to create one)

## IN Your Control

```
<UserControl Name="Control">
    <Button Visibility="{Binding Path=CloseButtonVisibility,ElementName=Control,Mode=TwoWay}"></Button>
</UserControl>
```

## While using your Control

```
<myControls:MonitorWindow x:Name="WindowFrame" MinHeight="400" CloseButtonVisibility="Hidden" />
```

This might help... :)

Answer (score 1):

You should do two things:

First you should expose the CloseButtonVisibility as a property.

The second thing is, in order to bind value to this property you should define this property as Dependcy property, see the following link for explanation on how to define dependency property:
[UNDERSTANDING: DEPENDENCY PROPERTIES IN SILVERLIGHT](http://geekswithblogs.net/Silverlight2/archive/2008/12/24/understanding-dependency-properties-in-silverlight.aspx)

Good Luck,
Lior